# Excel VBA find maximum value in range on specific sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I found that the following code is getting max value in range:

```
Cells(Count, 4)=Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Cells(m, 1),Cells(n, 1)))
```

How can I search within a specific sheet? `Data` sheet in this case

Like:

```
Worksheets(d).Cells(x, 4).Value = Worksheets("Data")... ????? FIND MAX ????
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will often work, but is missing a reference:

```
 worksheets("Data").Cells(Count, 4)=  Application.WorksheetFunction.Max _
    ( worksheets("Data").range( cells(m,1) ,cells(n,1) )
```

The text "cells" should be preceded by a reference to which worksheet the cells are on, I would write this:

```
worksheets("Data").Cells(Count, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max _
    ( worksheets("Data").range( worksheets("Data").cells(m,1) ,worksheets("Data").cells(n,1) )
```

This can also be written like this which is clearer:

```
with worksheets("Data")
    .Cells(Count, 4) =  Application.WorksheetFunction.Max _
                            ( .range( .cells(m,1) ,.cells(n,1) )
End With
```

I hope this helps.

Harvey

Comment: I like the one with the With statement, makes it a lot more clear, and also makes it faster. Note though that you shoudln't double-specify the worksheet! I mean, don't specify it before every range method, as that is not only useless, but it may lead to errors. This is enough: `Application.WorksheetFunction.Max  (range( .cells(m,1) ,.cells(n,1) )`

Comment: why would it lead to errors?  (I accept it's useless).  This has not been my experience.

Comment: It will only lead to an error if you try specifying a different worksheet for the outer .range object. (I know, why would you... But still...) Like I said, I'll dig around, and maybe post a question about this. Seems interesting.

Comment: @Vacip in that case getting an error is very useful, as it will help you identify a problem that might otherwise go unnoticed... By fully qualifying the range you are defining what you are expecting the parameters to be (ie cells on the sheet preceeding the range object).  If cells are defined by variables then putting the sheet object in front of the range will help stop unforeseen conditions NOT raising an error.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass any valid excel cell reference to the range method as a string.

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(range("Data!A1:A7"))
```

In your case though, use it like this, defining the two cells at the edges of your range:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Max _
    (range(worksheets("Data").cells(m,1),worksheets("Data").cells(n,1)))
```

Comment: range needs a reference to which worksheet the cells it refers to are going to be on.... see my answer for more info

Comment: This is not entirely true. The result of the range method is a collection of cells. That collection is **not** independent of the worksheet they are on, so you don't need to specify the worksheet again.

Comment: Yes you're right, that had not occurred to me before.  However, it doesn't hurt to put it in and make code very readable and clear.  I'm now wondering whether you can create a range object with areas on many sheets. I would say no...do you agree.

Comment: I stand corected, range is an object, not a method. Something is weird here. This is an interesting problem, I might just post a question about this. I can't rellay put my finger on it, but something feels off with this problem.

Comment: MySheet.range(..)  is a method of the sheet object that returns a range object.  The range object returned is instantiated (created) to contain references to cells that already exist, the cells it references depend on the parameters that were used.  

You can think of the range object itself containing a big collection of objects references of type cell the refer to cells that already exist.  OO can be really confusing at times...  MyRange.Parent is a property of the range object that returns a reference to a sheet object that exists already, and is the  sheet on which the range can be found.

Comment: Note that methods can have the same name as an object.  In the office object models this is pretty much always the case, which is great.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process quickly milion of cells to find MAX/MIN, you need heavier machinery. This code is faster then `Application.WorksheetFunction.Max`.

```
Function Max(ParamArray values() As Variant) As Variant
   Dim maxValue, Value As Variant
   maxValue = values(0)
   For Each Value In values
       If Value > maxValue Then maxValue = Value
   Next
   Max = maxValue
End Function

Function Min(ParamArray values() As Variant) As Variant
   Dim minValue, Value As Variant
   minValue = values(0)
   For Each Value In values
       If Value < minValue Then minValue = Value
   Next
   Min = minValue
End Function
```

Stolen from here: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/132404-max-min-vba.html