# Range object - why musn't I use a sheet sometimes

Tags: vba, excel

In this thread:

[Excel VBA find maximum value in range on specific sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31906571/excel-vba-find-maximum-value-in-range-on-specific-sheet)

I found a strange behaviour from the range object. I can't really put my finger on the problem, it is more like a feeling. Sometimes, you shouldn't preceed the range object with a sheet, sometimes you can. For me, it feels obvious, but I can't really explain it.
Can anyone clarify it maybe?

This works:

```
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 2)).Value = "X"
```

This feels really bad, but it works:

```
Sheets(2).Range(Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1), Sheets(2).Cells(2, 2)).Value = "X"
```

These don't work:

```
Sheets(1).Range(Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1), Sheets(2).Cells(2, 2)).Value = "X"
Sheets(1).Range("Sheet2!A1:B2").Value = "X"
```

I could change all the Cells(1,1) objects to Range("a1"), the results would be the same.

My best guess is that whenever the parameter passed to the Range object defines cells on a specific worksheet, you can't define a worksheet before the mentioned range. But when this is not the case, you are allowed to preceed the Range with a sheet object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here I think is that `Range` object can be child of both `application` and `worksheet` object.

As John Coleman wrote in his answer:

> [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841254.aspx) clearly states that "When used without an
>   object qualifier, this property [Range] is a shortcut for
>   ActiveSheet.Range"

It's actually not really wrong if you consider that "object qualifier" is not necessary to be parent of the `Range` object,  but it can also be within it ( `sheets(n)` is an object qualifier in `Range(Sheets(n).cells(y,x))`), so the possible scenarios:

- `Sheets(n).range(cells(y,x))` is valid and refers to a range in `Sheets(n)`
- `Sheets(n).range(Sheets(n).cells(y,x))` is also valid and refers to a range in `Sheets(n)`
- `Range(Sheets(n).cells(y,x))` is also valid and refers to a range still in `Sheets(n)`  - here the parent of `Range` is not the `activesheet`, but the **`application`** object!!
- `Range(cells(y,x))` is valid and refers to a range in `ActiveSheet`
- `Sheets(k).range(Sheets(n).cells(y,x))` is not valid as parent is `Sheets(k)` which doesn't contain cells in `Sheets(n)`

Comment: Application.range and object qualifier within the parameters - this is the key, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This seems a bit backwards. You can *always* put an explicit `Sheet` before a `Range` but sometimes you don't need to. `Range` *is* a child of the `WorkSheet` object in the Excel object model. VBA has a notion of *default objects* which allow you to sometimes keep parent objects implicit. In the case of `Range` the default parent object is `ActiveSheet`. If you are specifying a range on the active sheet then you can just refer to the range directly, but if you are trying to refer to a range on another sheet then you need to provide an explicit sheet reference. Your two examples don't really make sense since you are trying to construct a range on one sheet by referring to ranges on another sheet. That is sort of like saying you want the part of Germany which is between New York and Boston.

On edit: vacip has discovered an apparent anomaly. [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836512.aspx) clearly states that "When used without an object qualifier, this property [`Range`] is a shortcut for ActiveSheet.Range" Thus the in the following block of code, if run when Sheet 1 is active, both lines should be equivalent since the first is a "shortcut" for the second:

```
Sub test()
    Range(Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1), Sheets(2).Cells(2, 2)).Value = 1
    ActiveSheet.Range(Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1), Sheets(2).Cells(2, 2)).Value = 1
End Sub
```

But what actually happens is that the first line succeeds in altering a range on an inactive sheet but the second line fails. Odd.

Comment: Hmm, ok, thanks. I love the example. :) Another little anomaly than is this code, which works perfectly, even if you run it with Sheet(2) being the active sheet: `range(sheets(1).cells(1,1),sheets(1).cells(2,2)).Value="x"` So in this case, range is not considered to be a child of the active sheet (sh(2)), but more like an independent method...

Comment: @vacip Cool. I modified my post to incorporate it (including toning down the fist sentence). I see more clearly now what you were getting at. I'm voting your question up as being much more interesting than I thought at first.

Comment: Thanks! I have seen behaviour like this in VBA before. It's like Microsoft deliberately made VBA inconsistent or lenient in an attempt to make it user-friendly or fool-proof. Which is not a good thing IMO, as many beginners use it, and this hinders their understanding of the basic concepts of programming. Nevertheless, thanks for the answer. I'll leave this open for another day, then mark yours as answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems VBA is making assumptions about unqualified objects which may not be what you assume.  In general, an unqualified Range object will refer to the active sheet.  But if the range object is unqualified, and the included Cells arguments are qualified, then the range object will be qualified by the Cells.Worksheet object.

Always best to fully qualify.  For example:

```
With Sheets(2)
 .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 2)).Value = "X"
End With
```

although the following also works:

```
With Sheets(2)
 Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 2)).Value = "X"
End With
```