# VBA error : Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am using below code to clear the content from A2 cell till last. this code working fine if the active sheet is TimeStampWork. But If I on any other sheet, I am getting Error 1004, Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed error. How can I run the same code eventhough sheet is not active ?

```
Sub test1()
Dim ForClr As Worksheet
Set ForClr = Workbooks("Main.xlsm").Sheets("TimeStampWork")
ForClr.Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this macro in a normal code module or on a worksheet module?

Comment: Are you trying to run this code on all sheets or just in "TimeStampWork"?

Comment: Also **[Is the . in .Range necessary when defined by .Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368220/is-the-in-range-necessary-when-defined-by-cells)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Sub test1()
  Dim ForClr As Worksheet
  Set ForClr = Sheets("TimeStampWork")
  ForClr.range(ForClr.range("A2"), ForClr.range("A2").End(xlDown)).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: True. A little explanation would help though. [A similar discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907394/range-object-why-musnt-i-use-a-sheet-sometimes) The first `"A2"` in OP's code is referencing to cell A2 on the active sheet, and that makes the rest an impossible range declaration spanning through multiple sheets.

Comment: @vacip the *first* "A2" in OP's code *is* qualified to `ForClr`, it's the second that is unqualifed `Range("A2")` which will be on the ActiveSheet.

Comment: i didn't think it requires any further explanation. it is quite obvious and conceivable.

Comment: @ExcelinEfendisi what's obvious to you or me is not likely to be obvious to beginners or those otherwise unfamiliar with the object model or its quirks. The best answers here usually includes at least some brief diagnosis of the problem/error source along with an explanation of how the solution "works".

Comment: Fair enough David,so be it

Comment: Downvoting, for the reason @DavidZemens pointed out. There are more than enough "try this {code dump}" answers on this site - *too many* of them, actually. These answers don't teach anything, promote copy-pasta code, and only cause more [duplicate] questions to be asked when the OP hits the next roadblock because they haven't learned anything from any of the "try this {code dump}" answers they are getting here. Put some effort into your answers, and you'll be rewarded for making the Internet a better place. Or don't, and keep the wheel of ignorance spinning.

Answer (score 1):

In this one of your Range objects is unqualified, so is referencing the active sheet:

```
ForClr.Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).ClearContents
```

You should write instead

```
ForClr.Range(ForClr.Range("A2"), ForClr.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).ClearContents
```

Comment: Sorry David... I addressed your criticism...